# How to save any object which is declared as a class variable and initialized inside a test in JUnit

Tags: java, junit4

I am designing test cases in `JUnit`. My question is how to save any object which is declared as a class variable and initialized inside a test. Currently in such cases I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Below is the brief description-
I have three services listed below which needs to be tested-

1. **Service 1(login):** It accept a username password pair and returns
   cookies in response.
2. **Service 2(postmessage):** It accept a message,
   which must be supplied with cookies in the request and returns an
   unique id of posted message
3. **Service 3(markasread)**: It accept a
   message id, which must be supplied with cookies. The message id,
   which should be used in Service 3 is returned by service 2.

This is what I was expecting to work-

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ProfileTest{
    private String cookie;
    private String messageId;

    @Test
    public void loginTest(){
        String username = "demouser";
        String password = "demopassword";

        HttpResponse response = login(username, password);
        cookie = response.getCookie();

        assertEquals(response.getResponse(), "success");
    }

    @Test
    public void postmessageTest(){
        String message = "Hi, this is test message";
        HttpResponse response = postmessage(message, cookie);
        messageId = response.getCookie();

        assertEquals(response.getResponse(), "success");
    }

    @Test
    public void markasreadTest(){
        HttpResponse response = markasread(messageId, cookie);

        assertEquals(response.getResponse(), "success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't the order in which the tests are running?

Comment: @chrylis: Nice finding. The order must be always like this- loginTest->postmessageTest->markasreadTest. I can see in my eclipse, it is following the same order. but the variable `messageId` and `cookie` is changing to null outside the test. :(

Comment: Generally speaking, it's considered best practice to **not** have tests depend on each other.  They should be designed to run completely independently of one another.

Comment: Setup your member variables in an @Before annotated method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you cannot and you should not it. Each run of test cases will have its own copy of class variables. The idea behind this is just that each test case should run independently and should not depend on each other.

It may be possible through some junk code but I really don't have such a recommendation for you.

If possible then try to club the tescases together and run as a single one.

Comment: +1 because the general description is correct.  (Although it *is* possible to do, maybe with some horrid static variables, etc.)

Comment: Do you mean, I should put all three methods together to test `markasread` service? Also to test `postmessage` service, I need to put login method in it? Am i right? Does it sounds good?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Yes it makes sense to club them together and run as one test. Then you don't have to share the info among test cases.

Comment: @RaviJoshi The three tests make sense to be separate as they are testing 3 services. You should just remove the interdependance between them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do it is the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner creates a new instance of the test class per leaf method. It constructs the test class with the default constructor.

[BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java)

The relevant code is

```
protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
    return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: "Constructing the test class with the default constructor." Can you please provide any sample code for the same? Also is this recommended to use this approach?